# Access report pass parameter to subreports query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an access report which contains information about a given job.  I'm trying to add a subreport that will display some detail information about that job, but I need to pass the job's number into the query the 2nd report uses.  How is this done in access vba?

Is there some command which will let me run the query with the passed parameter before I display the subreport?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to connect a subreport to a main report is using the [LinkMasterFields/LinkChildFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa196324%28v=office.11%29.aspx) properties of the subreport control.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm a .NET programmer normally, I've never done much with Access vba like this.

Comment: @MAW74656: you should really spend time learning to use Access interactively. If you'd do that, basic things like this wouldn't be a mystery. Most of Access' programmability is built on top of the things you can do with point and click, so if you don't know how to do the point and click part, you'll end up thinking you need to code things that are really simple to do.